# Fomulario con PHP no funciona

Tags: php, formularios, validación

Estoy aprendiendo PHP a través de Udemy y me tope con un problema. A la hora de validad un formulario con PHP y no relleno un campo al enviar, debería saltarme un error en pantalla que me falta completar unos de los campos. Y es ese mensaje que no me estaría saltando. Y revisando el código no veo que tenga algún error del cual no entiendo porque no salta ese error

ARCHIVO INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Validación de formulario con PHP</title>
  <style>
    input {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <?php
    if( isset( $_GET['error'] ) ) {
      $error = $_GET['error'];
      if($error === 'faltan_datos') {
        echo '<strong style="color: red;">Introduce todos los datos en los campos requeridos</strong>';
      }
    }
  ?>

  <h1>Validación de formulario con PHP</h1>
  <form action="procesar_formulario.php" method="POST">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label> <br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" required pattern="[A-Z a-z]+"> <br>

    <label for="apellido">Apellido</label> <br>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" pattern="[A-Z a-z]+"> <br>

    <label for="edad">Edad</label> <br>
    <input type="number" name="edad" required pattern="[0-9]+"> <br>

    <label for="email">Email</label> <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" required> <br>

    <label for="pass">Contraseña</label> <br>
    <input type="password" name="pass" required> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

ARCHIVO PROCESAR_FORMULARIO.PHP 
Archivo donde valida si todo es correcto. Si no lo es, retorna al index.php y deberia mostrarme con el error en rojo

```
<?php

  $error = 'faltan_datos';

  if( !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido']) && !empty($_POST['edad']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) ) {

    $error = 'ok';
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  } else {
    $error = 'faltan_datos';
    header('Location:index.php?error=$error');
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Validación de formulario con PHP</title>
    <style>
      input {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1-Has probado a poner el protocolo (http) adelante, quedando:
header("Location: http://index.php?error=$error");

Comment: esto `header('Location:index.php?error=$error');` esta mal deberia ser algo como: `header('Location:index.php?error='.$error);` las comillas simples no imprimen valores de variables asique tienes que concatenarlo con el operador de union de cadenas  `.` o usar comillas dobles...

Comment: Lo otro que debes aprender a hacer es un `debug`basico que es validar la informacion que envias o manejas en las variables, como se hace pues dentro del `if( isset( $_GET['error'] ) ) {` colocas un `var_dump($_GET);` esto te permitira validar si entro al if por que existe el indice `error` y que valor contiene ese indice.

Comment: Si en el curso de udemy te muestran ejemplos de PHP mezclando vista (html) con modelo PHP, yo que tú me buscaría otro curso... Porque eso es una muy mala práctica.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tiene razón, aunque se puede cambiar por comillas dobles, en cuyo caso sí es posible meter variables dentro: `header("Location:index.php?error=$error");` Cristian, revisa la calidad del curso que estás haciendo, pues enseña malas prácticas, algunas ya te las señaló Jakala más arriba. Otra mala práctica es usar la super globlar `$_GET`, cuando el método del formulario es `POST`. Esto funciona a veces, pero en algunos servidores el código no funciona si usas una superglobal diferente, debes usar siempre la superglobal del método del formulario.